# SQL 2005 connection using classic ADO from Windows 2008 yields odd performance

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008, ado

UPDATE: Please see the updates below, as I'm adding more information to the bottom as I run into it.

I'm working on setting up a new web server running Windows Server 2008, connecting to another Windows 2003 Server with SQL Server 2005.  I'm running into some weird results when trying to run queries from the server to the SQL Server 2005 server.  Basically, ever other query has a fixed 625 millisecond overhead if results are returned, but no overhead when it's a non-query:

I'll let my sample VB script code do the talking:

```
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=thesqlserver;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=thedatabase"

t = Timer

for i = 1 to 20
    set rs = cn.Execute("select getdate()") //Note getting recordset here
    s = s & (timer - t) & VbNewLine
    t = Timer
next

for i = 1 to 20
    cn.Execute("select getdate()") //Note no recordset returned here
    s = s & (timer - t) & VbNewLine
    t = Timer
next

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set file = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\results.txt", 2, True)

file.WriteLine(s)
file.Close
```

Here are the actual results:

```
First Set - Returning recordset
0
0.625
0
0.6640625
0
0.625
0
0.625
0
0.625
0
0.625
0
0.625
0
0.625
0
0.625
0
0.6171875
Second Set - Non-query execution
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.015625
0
0
0
0
0
```

I'm baffled.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

In response to Kevin's answer, I tried running the same script directly from the SQL server.  The result was zero overhead all the way down.  The connection between the two servers is a crossover network cable connected to the second NICs of each server.

UPDATE:

New information.  I tried changing the servername in the "Server=" argument, and when using the internal (crossover cable) IP, it went from 625 milliseconds every even request, to 4,550 milliseconds ever even request (with the odd requests still at zero).  Then, changing it to the public IP made the overhead go away completely!  I must have something configured incorrectly on the internal NIC.

UPDATE:

Doing a Wireshark trace on the network activity, it appears the even requests are doing some sort of Windows challenge/response, and that's hanging.  These servers are not on a domain, and I'm using integrated security as shown above.  However, again, using integrated security is fine as long as I'm hitting the external IP. Also, removing integrated security, and explicitly providing credentials when using the internal IP also gets rid of the overhead.

Comment: Can you try creating a new recordset in the 2nd test but not assigning the results to it? e.g. add rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") before cn.Execute(). Haven't used old school asp in a long time so forgive me if that's not right. Anyway this will tell you if it's the sql server or the overhead to create a recordset. Also, timer is not especially precise in this sort of loop, try just comparing the time at the beginning and end of each loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, jamietre.  I tried this and got the exact same results as above -- adding the CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") in the second loop added no additional overhead.  Re: using a Timer, I thought about this too. But I think the precision is more an issue when you’re getting down to the millisecond.  Before I used a timer and a log, I used a message box between each iteration, and I saw the same results: every odd request would pop the message box instantly, every even request would pause 1/2 second or more to pop up the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the only solution I can find is to reference the external IP vs. the internal IP.  I'm not sure if this has any performance impact (i.e. is the route the packets take longer now), but at least it's working.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overhead in setting up the recordset object but does seem 625ms is a bit steep, it might be down to having to destroy the existing recordset and put the new one in.

Either way if I’m performing an action query and don’t need the recordset I always use the extra option adExecuteNoRecords so that no recordset is setup and the query will execute faster.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  But if I run the exact same script from the SQL server, I get zero overhead.  And it's odd that it's always exactly the every other request.  This is the case if I let it run for 100 iterations -- it alternates between 0 and 625, always.  I'll update my original post with this information.